# Incorrect URL in Wordpress leads to broken images

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I just transferred a website from their previous host to hosting with me. Obviously, I had to change some of the links that pointed to the images to make them display correctly. Unfortunately, it's a huge mess. There were some links described in the mysql database, but i got into MySQL and replaced all of those with the correct link. Originally, it linked to

`http://localhost/...`

I now need it to link to

`http://[subdomain].[website].net/`

I've gone through every line of code i could find with fgrep in linux and i can't find where it's inserting localhost. Any ideas where localhost could be stored, if not in the database (as far as i can tell) and not in the physical code? I'm assuming it's a PHP variable somewhere. I'm not sure which, but i already made sure that

`<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>`

was set to the correct uri. Any help would be greatly appreciated. thank you.

**EDIT**

I tried to replace the database information correctly from a clean copy of the database. I used the serialize php script and it didn't work. the images are still not showing up and they're still routing back to
`http://localhost`

I'm not sure what to do about it. Any more suggestions?

Comment: Did you check out the post body for all the posts?

Comment: Dump the database and search the sql file for localhost, just in case.

Comment: i did, i dumped it and replaced every single instance of it in the database

Comment: post body? would the post body be IN the database? or.. where would i find it

Answer (score 1):

1) Check page source and see exactly where the image URLs point to. Some missing image links may be hardcoded to point to the theme folder or other locations.

2) Did you also move /wp-content/uploads?

3) Dumping the database and doing a find/replace with a text editor will break URLs that are in serialized data. You have to use a tool to correctly deserialize/re-serialize data. See [interconnectit.com WordPress Serialized PHP Search Replace Tool](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)

Comment: ok. interesting. im going to look into this serialized thing and get back to you. I didnt move uploads or wp-content. the URLs are pointing to the correct image except for the fact that SOME of them have http://localhost still

Comment: The interconnectit.com tool works perfectly and will correctly replace URLs. Try it with a new database dump. If you *didn't* move wp-content/uploads/, that's why your images are missing. Some missing image links may be hardcoded to point to the theme folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that you replaced every occurrence of localhost in the database, then the most likely next culprit is the browser cache, so I recommend you to delete the cache of your browser just to be sure, as this depends on your browser search for the appropriate method, but, for example, on Internet Explorer open the Developer Tools (F12) and go to Cache->Erase cache for this domain.

Comment: I've done that. Actually, if i remove EVERY occurrence of it in the database, the page breaks. it starts saying something to the effect of "fatal error: printPage() not pointing to a type object in ..." something to that effect. so i went in and tried to fix that but i was literally chasing error after error that popped up as i fixed another. i went after like 5 or 6 different errors and stopped. what doesnt make sense to me is that if i leave the "pagebuilder" data alone, the site works fine. if i change the value of "pagebuilder" to have the correct site, it gives me those billions of errors

Comment: if pagebuilder is left alone, everything on the site works but the images. if i change pagebuilder, it cuts almost everything out and just gives me error after error after error to correct.

Comment: didnt work. i went through the entire process and it didnt work. im at a loss now. i have no idea where to go from here

Comment: should i just change them all and try to deal with the error after error after error?